# magento SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '363624' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, magento

i have migrated a mgento installation doing the following:

1. copied all files
2. exported the db
3. imported the db using mysql workbench
4. changed the base_url's to the new domain
5. updated local.xml to the correct settings

now im getting:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '363624' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I have searched the db for this key 363624 , but it is not duplicated as the messages says

how can i solve this ?

Comment: Which table is giving you this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not duplicated but rather something must be *trying* to duplicate it.

How did you export the database? I would check that the dumped SQL file has the line "**SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;**" or similar at the top.

If not, I would drop the database and add this line to the top of the file:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

... and this line to the bottom:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

... then try again.

Comment: hi I'm getting the same error but my problem is I cannot drop the database as this problem started recently. i have too many products and data. How can you apply this solution to my situation? thank you.

Comment: Don't you think this is a bad idea to disable foreign key checks ? It is there for a reason actually. This can't be a long terms solution.

Comment: A combination of this solution and Oscars solution worked for me

Answer (score 31):

This helped me (clearing some of the tables):

Enter your Magento database and run following sql query:

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export ; 
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import ; 
TRUNCATE log_customer ; 
TRUNCATE log_quote ; 
TRUNCATE log_summary ; 
TRUNCATE log_summary_type ; 
TRUNCATE log_url ; 
TRUNCATE log_url_info ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info ; 
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online ; 
TRUNCATE report_event ;
```

After that need to clear var/session dir (If your session stored in files) cause you will get same error until you clear session files.

Comment: This works. Figured the log tables were getting updated mid export causing inconsistencies.

Comment: A combination of this solution and redjam13's solution worked for me

Comment: After this also need clear session directory if your session stores in files.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error.

For me, it turns out that the export was taking so long with the site staying 'live' that the end of the export was out of sync with the beginning.

Specifically, the 'log_visitor_info' table had about 100 more records than some of the other related visitor log tables, so the DB is trying to create a record ID from another table that already exists here.

I just deleted the last 100 or so records from this specific table and things worked again without the error.
Alternatively it looks like you can mash on the f5 key until you increment past that already-existing ID and Magento will start working again.

I suspect that putting the store in maintenance mode before the export may help with this particular error.

Comment: This answer was so helpful - I found by comparing the Ids of the log_visitor_info table with the generated Id in the error msg that it was indeed around 10 records out of sync. Hence, hitting refresh as you suggest approx. 10 times fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was UTF-8 without BOM encoding in text editor. I've change to UTF-8 with BOM and everything works fine.

Comment: That's pretty weird considering that Magento recommends UTF-8 without BOM for everything.

Answer (score 0):

if the error showing for the table `'cataloginventory_stock_item' having 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID' index,`

then please sure that you are passing different product SKU from your script.

Comment: If you provide more explanations of the cause of the problem, and *how* your solution solves the problem, this may be a good answer. I am not sure how this addresses the problem, as it is about migrating magento.

Answer (score 0):

Run this sql query in your magento data base.

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export ;

TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import ; 

TRUNCATE log_customer ; 

TRUNCATE log_quote ; 

TRUNCATE log_summary ; 

TRUNCATE log_summary_type ; 

TRUNCATE log_url ; 

TRUNCATE log_url_info ; 

TRUNCATE log_visitor ; 

TRUNCATE log_visitor_info ; 

TRUNCATE log_visitor_online ; 

TRUNCATE report_event ;
```

First you have to check the 'log_visitor_info' table structure. In this table 'visitor_id' field is should default value as null. If default value is set as anything you should run this below query, Otherwise you leave it the below query just execute the above query.

```
ALTER TABLE `log_visitor_info` CHANGE `visitor_id` `visitor_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Visitor ID';
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because table `log_visitor_info` contains extra rows of visitors that doesn't exist in `log_visitor` table, as explained in @creuzerm's comment;

if you run these queries you must have the same result

```
SELECT MAX(`visitor_id`) FROM `log_visitor`;

SELECT MAX(`visitor_id`) FROM `log_visitor_info`;
```

to solve this problem you need to delete these extra invalid rows with the following query

```
DELETE FROM `log_visitor_info` WHERE `visitor_id` > ( SELECT MAX(`visitor_id`) FROM `log_visitor` );
```

for consistency run this too

```
DELETE FROM `log_visitor_online` WHERE `visitor_id` > ( SELECT MAX(`visitor_id`) FROM `log_visitor` );
```